Boundary conditions in quantum mechanics
I'm having some trouble understanding the role of boundary conditions in (non-relativistic) quantum mechanics.
EDIT:
The following text talks a bit about Bloch's theorem, but this was just supposed to be an example on why I find boundary conditions a bit confusing.
My real question is more in general about boundary conditions.
I don't really understand why in some context I am allowed to choose the boundary conditions. That's my understanding at least: there is some freedom of choice when it comes to boundary conditions.
Obviosly a periodic function in Bloch's theorem makes all the calculations easier, but in the end what we really want is a prediction that is reliable, rather than the easy way out.
So are we really free in our choice of boundary conditions?
Are we always free in our choice, or just sometimes?
Why? Why not? Does this depend on the physical properties of the system? Do different boundary conditions predict different behaviours for the system under study?
And if you want to be specific on my example, you could relate all this questions to the periodic boundary conditions of Bloch's theorem.
Older text:
I don't know if this is still useful at this point. This is my older question that caused some confusion. This is just supposed to be an example that shows how I find this topic confusing.
I was studying Bloch's theorem, and in this context we impose periodic boundary conditions on our system.
The problem is that I don't really understand why we are allowed to do that!
In this case we are studying a finite crystal. I was expecting to impose that the wavefunction is 0 at the border of the crystal, rather then periodic boundary conditions.
The only other spatially finite system I studied was the particle in a box. In this case we do impose that the wavefunction is 0 at the border of the box.
This makes sense to me as the wavefunction is 0 outside of the box, and we want the wavefunction to be continuous.
In the case of the crystal our particles are once again "confined in a box", but we don't impose that the wavefunction to be 0 on the border of the crystal.
This makes no sense to me: I would have supposed the wavefunction to be 0 outside of the crystal, and so I would have imposed the wavefunction to be 0 on the border of the crystal.
Tl;dr
What are exactly boundary conditions for a wavefunction? Am I allowed to choose the boundary conditions I like the most? What are exactly my options, and where do my options come from?

As long as you are not interested in surface effects, the idea is that you first consider PBC (and a finite volume), and then go to the thermodynamic limit. Hopefully, then, all bulk properties are independent of the boundary conditions employed. IIRC, Ashcroft and Mermin discuss this briefly. This for sure has been asked here before...

This question is similar to: Boundary conditions for crystals. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TobiasFünke This question is similar but not the same as the one you linked. Moreover, the answers to the previous questions are definitely not satisfactory. I'll propose reopening this question.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Regarding your second point: Then one could also argue to close this and leave the other open, since it already has answers; in case, consider to write an answer there instead. Regarding your first point: I really don't see where the difference is. Can you elaborate (so I might consider to vote to re-open, too)?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36228/2451 and links therein.

I still don't see why the previously linked duplicate isn't exactly the same what you asked. You say it is okay to discuss the example of a solid (which it does), and I would say it answered all of your questions. --That being said, you are always free to choose boundary conditions as you like; whether or not this models an experimental situation is a different story. Sometimes certain boundary conditions are more "natural" than others, and sometimes the choice does not make a difference, e.g. for the case of a solid in the TDL (of course with caveats, as elaborated already a bit).

@TobiasFunke "Sometimes certain boundary conditions are more "natural" than others," so then the question should be in a single sentence: why the periodic boundary condition for the wave function is more natural than anything else, especially being zero outside the body and this followed by a request for an intuitive, not analytical, handwaving verbiage. The utilitarian answer is that you don't get the band structure that way, but there ought to be a better explanation somewhere.

@hyportnex To be fair, you also have to consider the next part of the sentence: "sometimes the choice does not make a difference, e.g. for the case of a solid in the thermodynamic limit (TDL)"--which is the case for introduction to solid state physics. BTW: You can also "bypass" the use of the BvK PBC with a finite volume, but this then requires a much more heavy mathematical apparatus. See e.g. this.

This paper might be of interest, too.
